# How to trim String directory in java

Tags: java, string, trim

I am trying to trim my directory which is in string format in java . I only want images/filename and want to remove directory before images.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [Asking Questions - Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1):

## Split

This answer covers both forwardslashed directories and backslash directories.

Sample Input:

```
C:/hello/myAwesomeImage.png
C:\hello\myAwesomeImage.png
```

**Forwardslashes**

```
String [] myFile = "C:/hello/myAwesomeImage.png".split("/"); // split it
String myFileName = myFile[myFile.length - 1]; // Extract filename
```

**Backslashes**

```
String [] myFile = "C:\hello\myAwesomeImage.png".split("\\"); // split it
String myFileName = myFile[myFile.length - 1]; // Extract filename
```

Output: `"myAwesomeImage.png"`

Alternatively, if you don't want to split...

## RegEx

**Backslash + No Extension**

```
String myFile = "C:\\hello\\myAwesomeImage.png".matches("[ \\w-]+?(?=\\.)");
```

Output: `"myAwesomeImage"`

**Backslash + Extension**

```
 String myFile = "C:\\hello\\myAwesomeImage.png".matches("[ \w-]+\....");
```

Output: `"myAwesomeImage.png"`

**Forwardslash + Extension**

```
String myFile = "C:/hello/myAwesomeImage.png".matches("[^\/]+(?=\.*$)");
```

Output: `"myAwesomeImage.png"`

**Forwardslash + No Extension**

```
String myFile = "C:/hello/myAwesomeImage.png".matches("[^\/]+(?=\..*$)");
```

Output: `"myAwesomeImage"`

Answer (score 0):

Java has a powerful built-in File API. [java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is particularly useful.

I would recommend using this rather than string manipulation, Advantages include portability across operating systems which may use / or .

```
File myFile = new File("C:/hello/myAwesomeImage.png");
System.out.println(myFile.getName());
System.out.println(myFile.getParentFile().getName());
System.out.println(myFile.getParentFile().getParent());
```

Output

```
myAwesomeImage.png
hello
C:
```

Comment: I'd argue that opening a filestream and reading a files' content is less efficient than string-manipulation. Especially if you have tons of files that you need to process. I'd rather keep them as strings in that case.

Comment: The above code never actually "touches" the disk. I'd go for less error prone approach every time.

Comment: Error prone in what way? Like, the fact that a disk might get disconnected and the program crashes or that the file is unaccessable and the program crashes or that there's no readpermission on the file (i can go on).

Comment: Error prone in terms of implementation: "[^\/]+(?=\.*$)" vs getName(). Please note the above code using File API does not access disk unless you call certain functions. I use Linux not windows, and the above new File("C:/hello/myAwesomeImage.png") works just fine.

Comment: Yes it works, but to call it "less error prone" is a strange one, since there's a lot more things that can go wrong runtime-wise than with basic stringmanipulation that can be statically evaluated.